# Storing data into Java local APP

Tags: java, caching, local

I'm looking for a way to store data on my client application.

I want to avoid using online database because there are just some variables to store.

I couldn't find any solution to simply cache data into the app.

The data should be accessible at the application start up and must be cleaned after 2 weeks (i guess we can store an expire date for such behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

Try LevelDB. It's fast, light weight and efficient/fast.
And It seems it'll fit your needs.

Tutorial/usage:
https://github.com/dain/leveldb

MVN:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.iq80.leveldb/leveldb